# Gradle Build fail when i import an external library

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, build.gradle

I added a new library to my android studio project and now I am getting this error when I run it:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR: 
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command' /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" finished with non-zero value 3
BUILD FAILED
Total time:17 mins 33.841 secs
1 error
0 warning
```

I added the library in app/libs. I used right click and add as a library.
[add as library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlVO2.png)

I read that is possible fix this error if i put the library in External Libraries instead of Project/app/libs but i dont know how to do it.
  [External libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv68C.png)

This is my build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nameht.pruebas"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile files('libs/symja-2016-03-07.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the lib twice. Ones using this `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` and ones using this `compile files('libs/symja-2016-03-07.jar')`. Try removing one of these and things should work fine. I recommend to remove this `compile files('libs/symja-2016-03-07.jar')` as then you don't need to worry about adding jar from lib individually.

Your gradle file should look like this -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {                      <-- This is important
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nameht.pruebas"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```